# Excel COUNTIF dates

Tags: excel, worksheet-function, countif

I have cells that have both a date and time in them, e.g. `8/7/2015  5:47:15 PM`.  The general text seems to be `42223.7411458333`.  I am looking for a function that will search column A for any cell containing `8/7/2015` and count how many. I currently have `=COUNTIF(A:A,"8/7/2015")` but that returns 0.

Comment: One option would be to create a column with `Int(A1)` - say, column B, and then `countif(B:B, "8/7/2015")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest way is to use `COUNTIFS` (which is like `COUNTIF` but allows multiple criteria) to count all datetimes on the given date.

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A, ">=8/7/2015", A:A, "<8/8/2015")
```

If you need to get the date from another cell, you can use the `&` operator, for example if B1 contains `8/7/2015`:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A, ">=" & B1, A:A, "<" & B1 + 1)
```

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly!  I really like the option of having an individual cell control the input

Answer (score 1):

`E1=SUMPRODUCT(--(INT(A:A)=C1))`

```
C1=int(datetime)
```

where `A` column contains the date time value and `C1` has the date you want the count of

[image]`